# getnameinfo() always rises "Illegal opcode" error from Valgrind

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, c, networking

I have a Raspberry Pi 2, running Raspbian.

I'm trying to get informations by IP addresses, such as aliase(s), hostname(s) and so on.

According to the man, `gethostbyaddr` is obsolete: better use `getnameinfo()`.

No matter what I try, `valgrind` detects a `SIGILL` during a `getnameinfo()` call.

I checked the proper filling of `sockaddr_in sa` fields, the actual value of the IP address I want to resolve, the returning value of `getnameinfo()`, all the necessary `#include`.

Yet, executing the code below with `valgrind`

```
int temp_ret = 0;
struct sockaddr_in sa;
char hbuf[NI_MAXHOST], sbuf[NI_MAXSERV];
sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
/* temp is a personal struct; saddr is an unsigned long int */
sa.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(temp->saddr);
temp_ret = getnameinfo((struct sockaddr*)&sa, sizeof(sa), hbuf,
    sizeof(hbuf), sbuf, sizeof(sbuf), NI_NAMEREQD);
if(temp_ret > 0) {
    /* handle error */
}
/* printf below is not reached */
printf("%s %s\n", hbuf, sbuf);
```

returns

```
==742== 
==742== Process terminating with default action of signal 4 (SIGILL)
==742==  Illegal opcode at address 0x485F6F4
==742==    at 0x485F6F4: ??? (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so)
```

By executing the code without `valgrind`, it simply crashes doing things fine before calling `getnameinfo()`.

The error code above was made by 3.11.0 version: I updated `valgrind` from the 3.6 version I found in the repositories to the 3.11.0 downloaded from the site; the error simply changed layout but the content was still the same.

I hope this is not because of something wrong with `getnameinfo()`; anyway, the following are my system informations:

```
$ uname -a
```

> Linux raspberrypi 4.1.7-v7+ #817 SMP PREEMPT Sat Sep 19 15:32:00 BST 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux

```
$ cat /etc/debian_version
```

> 8.0

Any advice would be really appreciated.

**Edit 1**: on my laptop running Ubuntu, calling `getnameinfo()` returns no error, even with `valgrind` activated.

**Edit 2**: running `ldd --version` on both my RPi and my laptop I get respectively:

> ldd (Debian GLIBC 2.19-18+deb8u1) 2.19
>
> ldd (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.19-0ubuntu6.6) 2.19

So, `getnameinfo()` has issues with GLIBC (RPi) but works fine with EGLIBC (Ubuntu).

Comment: Are you compiling with `gcc`? If so, what arguments are you passing to it?

Comment: All my files are compiled with `gcc -Wall -Wunused`: I changed the flag from `NI_NAMEREQD` ("If set, then an error is returned if the hostname cannot be determined": maybe that was the problem) to `NI_NUMERICHOST | NI_NUMERICSERV`: this time no crash, but it returns all the IP addresses as they were, no hostname resolved, and services are all `0`. So, no resolve yet, but at least it doesn't crash.

Comment: Ah, interesting. "Illegal instruction" has me suspecting it was maybe a `-Ox` optimization problem or something... Not sure about what's going on with `getnameinfo()`, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346194/how-to-use-getnameinfo-instead-of-gethostbyname) might bring some clarification.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a WONTFIX bug in valgrind that is discussed on [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20066654/73826). The fix for that bug, which works for me, is to comment out the line in a preloaded .so file to force the glibc version to be used. You could see if you can comment out the line in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so to avoid the preload.